# Flutter cannot parse regex

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

Flutter cannot parse [this working regex](https://regex101.com/r/H9NUV7/3), and doesn't return any error or info.

```
(?<=id=)[^&]+
```

However, when I add it into my Flutter app:

```
print("before");
new RegExp(r'(?<=id=)[^&]+');
print("after");
```

It doesn't do anything, doesn't return any error. The `print("after");` never gets executed. It doesn't completly freeze the app, because it's in async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart compiled for the Web supports lokbehinds, but the current version of native Dart (including Flutter) does not support lookbehinds ([source](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34935#issuecomment-446097844)).

In your case, you want to match a string after a specific string. All you need is to declare a capturing group in your pattern and then access that submatch:

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r"id=([^&]+)");
String s = "http://example.com?id=some.thing.com&other=parameter; http://example.com?id=some.thing.com";
Iterable<Match> matches = regExp.allMatches(s);
for (Match match in matches) {
    print(match.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
some.thing.com
some.thing.com
```

Here, `id=([^&]+)` matches `id=` and then the `([^&]+)` capturing group #1 matches and captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `&`. Note you may make it safer if you add `[?&]` before `id` to only match `id` and not `thisid` query param: `[?&]id=([^&]+)`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34935

> Bring Dart's RegExp support in line with JavaScript: lookbehinds, property escapes, and named groups.

Comment: So... Its not supported in current version of Flutter? So I will have to use just `id=[^&]+` and then ReplaceAll `id=` with `''` .

Comment: Yes, Flutter depends on Dart for RegExp and Dart limits itself to what is supported in the browser, but they are a bit behind, because I think your example is now supported in recent browser versions, but not yet in Dart. I don't have deep RegExp knowledge and I'm not sure what a good workaround would be.